# Call JQuery function in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got this JQuery code:

file: code.js

```
 jQuery(function(){

        function renderSVG(){
            //Something
        };
 });
```

File: index.html

```
<script>
      function mostrarOdonto() {
          renderSVG();
      };
</script>
```

But i got a problem here:
http://i.gyazo.com/9550a64fc16c7570107706fb2162d84f.png in renderSVG() inside mostrarOdonto()
"Uncaught ReferenceError: renderSvg is not defined"

I tried $renderSVG(); but doesnot work. Anyone can help me?

Thanks so much!

PD: Sorry bad english

Answer (score 2):

That is caused by javascript closures.  It is local within the jQuery call and not accessible outside.  You can read more about it here: [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

You can declare objects outside of the jQuery function call to have it available globally. i.e.:

```
function RenderSVG(){
 //Do Stuff
}

jQuery(function(){
   RenderSVG();
});
```

This ensures that it is accessible outside the jquery scope
or if you really need it within jQuery you can go the route of a jQuery Plugin a la: [jQuery docs](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Example:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.renderSVG = function( options ) {
       //Do Stuff with canvas since it would be referenced in this.
    }; 
}( jQuery ));
```

Then you can call it like: `$('#mycanvas').renderSVG({/*options*/});`

#### Update 1:

You have to ensure when your code is called after loading jQuery and any plugins.
in your `<head>` tag
you should put `<script src=".../jquery.min.js">` or whatever your file for jquery is called
followed by any plugin scripts ...`src="jquery.svg.js"`, then you put your code:

```
<script>
   function RenderSVG(){
   }

   //And most important is that you call it after it is ready. In this example
   //I use jQuery(window).load you can also use jQuery(document).ready
   jQuery(window).load(function(){
      RenderSVG();
   });
</script>
```

if it still doesn't work you have to ensure the library for the svg methods aren't doing something weird.  To be sure we would have to know the library you are using.

Comment: My renderSVG function uses JQuery methods, and show me errors here: clear() method
http://gyazo.com/e0ed4d5ea3417e2152d1f25f1936e219.png
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function `renderSVG()` is a local function,since it is inside `jQuery(function(){ }`. It is valid only in that scope , So it is not accessible via other scopes. So try it like this.

```
<script>
      jQuery(function(){
         function mostrarOdonto() {
             renderSVG();
         };
      };
</script>
```

Comment: Or declare renderSVG as a variable outside of jQuery

Comment: It would work. Bu the issue is, from that moment on, that variable will be global. It is not a good practice to declare global variables.

Comment: @Xl-lord Please explain why it is not a good practice to declare global variables.

Comment: Hi, but it doesnot work, sayd: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined 
And in the final line need "});"

http://i.gyazo.com/3ddf061f272a4d173e77a9d332cf37ab.png

Answer (score 0):

You can Do it in this way [JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/pSJL4/84/)

**HTML:**

```
 <input type="button" value="go" onclick=" mostrarOdonto();">
```

**Scripts:**

```
 $.renderSVG = function() {
  alert("I am calling form jquery");
 };

 $(document).ready(function() {
  alert("function is ready to use now");
 });

 function mostrarOdonto() {
      $.renderSVG();
  };
```

This should work as per your requirement. The Jquery part can go into your Code.js file.

Comment: But my renderSVG is a function: function renderSVG(){ //code }; see my question, thanks.

Comment: if you want renderSVG to be a Java Script function the function should be in calling scope. either do like above or call it from jquery scope- `jQuery(function(){function mostrarOdonto() {          renderSVG(); }; };`

Answer (score 0):

I think could help you it's simple and straight forward

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 mostrarOdonto();

});

 function renderSVG() {
    alert("Testing purpose only");
};

function mostrarOdonto() {
    renderSVG();
};
```